# Внешняя авторизация

Tags: авторизация, php

Как сделать внешнюю авторизацию на php (через социальные сети/почту)?
Как пример сайта с такой авторизацией можно рассмотреть даже данный сайт. [Авторизация на hashcode.ru](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/account/signin/) Или вот ещё: [Freespace.by](http://Freespace.by)
Я конечно понимаю что можно использовать сервис Loginza.ru, но хотелось бы обойтись без него.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предыдущие комментаторы правы, хочу описать общую последовательность:
во всех случаях

- сначала мы перенаправляем пользователя на внешний сервис,
- после аутентификации сервис перенаправляет пользователя обратно на наш адрес. При этом он добавляет к адресу *"секретное значение"* или мы делаем проверочный запрос на внешний сервис.
- наш сервис выставляет *свою* идентификационную куку этому пользователю (или прописывает значение "авторизован" в сессию).

Это принципиальный момент: нет способа прочитать или записать куку в чужом домене! Куку мы ставим сами, после того как поверили в ответ внешнего сервиса.

Чтобы сообщение от внешнего сервиса было достоверным, обычно используют ассиметричные ключи. То есть "секретное значение" можно подделать только зная ключ.

Я могу порекомендовать библиотеку [HibridAuth](https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth). В ней есть адаптеры во все популярные социалки и простые примеры использования.

Answer (score 2):

Читаем про [openId](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID), ищем [реализацию на пхп](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid/lightopenid). Встраиваем у себя на сайте и радуемся жизни.

Answer (score 2):

Эти сайты предоставляют так называемый API (Application Programming Interface). Про Facebook, например, можно глянуть [у них самих на сайте](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login).